# Ложить/класть?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В каких случаях используется слово **ложить**, а в каких **класть**? Спасибо.

Comment: Слышала даже такой вариант - подлАживать (документ).

Comment: @Елена "Подлаживать" - вообще-то такой глагол существует, только он имеет  другой смысл: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C. Подлаживать документ = подправлять документ.

Answer (score 6):

Вместо *ложить* всегда следует говорить **класть**. Строго говоря, глагола *ложить* в русском языке нет, есть приставочные образования: **положить, доложить, выложить** и т. д. А без приставки глагол не употребляется. Так что если Вам захочется сказать *ложит*, говорите **кладёт**.

Comment: А что на счет выражения "ложись на спину"? Не станешь же говорить "уклади себя на спину",

Comment: а когда говорят, что в русском языке этого нет, то ссылаются на какой-то конкретный словарь? Или на какой источник?

Comment: Ложись от глагола ложиться. А такой возвратный глагол в языке есть.

Answer (score 1):

В учебнике русского языка для 5 класса есть табличка, где так и написано: ПОЛОЖИТЬ, но КЛАСТЬ. Просто надо помнить об этом.